# Why python executable file is not opening on the another computer?

Tags: tkinter

I have written code a GUI(tkinter). After completion, I have changed it to an executable file using pyinstaller. It worked on my computer but when I checked it in another system. 
So many errors were popped up. I tried for solutions but there are of no use.

I also checked with cx_Freeze and auto-py-to-exe. But, they too didn't work.

Please fix or tell me the solution.

I am using Python3.8 and Win10-64bit Operating System.

Comment: I just went through this also.  Did you copy the entire directory inside the dist directory and move that to the other computer?  I made sure I did NOT use the --onefile option.  That was a problem for me.

Comment: What are the errors? Probably a file or package you are importing is missing, and that can cause a casdade of errors.

Comment: Yeah entirely copied the directory.

Comment: It is showing like .dll files are missing..

Comment: Or Can I use py2exe?? For that I need to downgrade my Python 3 to Python 2